# Efficient complex masked moving window analysis

Tags: python, arrays, moving-average, sliding-window

I am developing a moving window algorithm in Python which will be used to slide across large numpy arrays (My test array dimensions are 6349x9849 for example). I need to calculate a number of different statistics in a 25 x 25 moving window which is masked by a 9x9 window, at each pixel location.

There is one caveat as well which stopped me using convolve (which is super quick for calculating the mean in a moving window for example): if the central pixel in the moving window is 0, I set the statistic value to -9999 as a flag, or if the 25x25 moving window contains more than half 0 values, I set the statistic value to -1 as a flag. I can then deal with the flags later.

I have written Python code to do this which works, but it is the first time in my Python learning that I have worked with particularly large amounts of data and thus encountered efficiency issues - it takes a very long time with the code I have written (talking around 6 hours per statistic for this image size...!).

**I would like to ask for any suggestions how I can do this much more efficiently.** I want to optimise the code first, before just throwing more computing power at it (I believe I could use multiprocessing module to do this for example).

My code, for one example statistic (standard deviation) is below. I repeat this line for each statistic (I have 6 statistics to calculate):

```
# Calculate the standard deviation of the masked moving window
stats_std = [-9999 if ds_array[row,column] == 0
else -1 if np.count_nonzero(ds_array[row-border_buff:row+border_buff+1,column-border_buff:column+border_buff+1]) < (outer_box**2)/2
else np.std([i for i in np.ma.compressed(np.ma.masked_array(ds_array[row-border_buff:row+border_buff+1,column-border_buff:column+border_buff+1],mask)) if i!=0])
for row in range(border_buff,m-border_buff)
for column in range(border_buff,n-border_buff)]

# Reshape the list into the image dimensions
stats_std = np.reshape(stats_std,(m-2*border_buff,n-2*border_buff))
```

I can provide a sample subset array and desired output to trial on if required, not sure the best way to provide this however, please let me know if it's required to make the above clearer.

P.s. I have tried one way of converting the 2d array into 3d of all the 25x25 subsets of the array, and then computing the 6 statistics effectively in one step per subset hoping for significant computational savings.. but this resulted in a MemoryError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) lets you calculate complex things on huge images [efficiently and using very little memory](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use). It's LGPL, runs on Linux, macOS and Windows, and works on every version of Python. Most linuxes have it in the package manager.

When you do an operation like `a + b` in pyvips, it doesn't actually do any processing, it just adds another node to a graph of image processing operations. When you finally write the result somewhere, the entire graph evaluates and it streams the image through your system in a set of small pieces and in parallel.

Because the intermediate images don't really exist, you only need a small amount of memory, and because its parallel, it's quick.

For example, you could do your sdev calculation like this:

```
import sys
import pyvips

# load the input image ... the access hint means we will only make a single
# top-to-bottom pass over image, and it can therefore be streamed 
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')

# our convolution ... total pixels in an M x M window
# it's a simple box filter, so we can use a seperable convolution 
# (two 1D filters at 90 degrees)
window_size = 25
size = window_size * window_size
sum_mask = pyvips.Image.new_from_array([1] * window_size)

# standard deviation ... sum and sum of squares
s = image.convsep(sum_mask)
s2 = (image * image).convsep(sum_mask)
sdev = ((s2 - (s * s / size)).abs() / (size - 1)) ** 0.5

# find all zero input pixels ... these become -9999 in the output
sdev = (image == 0).ifthenelse(-9999, sdev)

# find all pixels where more than half of the window is zero ... these become
# -1 in the output
# pyvips uses 255 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE
more_than_half_zero = (image == 0).convsep(sum_mask) > 255 * size / 2
sdev = more_than_half_zero.ifthenelse(-1, sdev)

sdev.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ vipsheader x.jpg 
x.jpg: 10000x10000 uchar, 1 band, b-w, jpegload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e python3 sdev.py x.jpg x.pfm
81432:4.11
```

To make a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel PFM (a simple format that can store float values) from a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel jpg image, where each pixel in the PFM is the sdev of the corresponding 25 x 25 window, plus your rules for zeros. It takes 4s on this desktop, and a maximum of 81mb of memory.

I can get the memory use down a bit by only using a single thread, but of course it's a lot slower:

```
$ VIPS_CONCURRENCY=1 /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e python3 sdev.py x.jpg x.pfm
54128:16.92
```

Only 54mb of memory now, but 17s of time.

You can read and write images to and from numpy arrays as well, see the [chapter in the docs](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/intro.html#numpy-and-pil).

Comment: Great, almost there with it. On the convolution, is there a way to ignore no data values? For example, i'd like to perform a convolution which calculates the average of a masked array, but don't want no data (in this example no data = 0) values taken into account.

Comment: I guess you'd need to do two convolutions, one to get the sum of each window, and one to find the number of non-zero pixels in each window. Divide one by the other and you should get a masked average.

Comment: Thanks, this is also what I had in mind. How would I count the non-zero values in the mask? I did try and do the sum of the true value (255) then dividing by 255 but I now understand it doesn't work like that and just populates with 255 or 0 (i.e. that's just a way to check if there is any 0s in the mask rather than counting them).

Comment: Something like `(x != 0).conv([[1] * window_size] * window_size) / 255`, ie. test for not zero to get just 0/255 pixels, then sum pixels in the window, then divide by 255. You can do the divide as part of the conv and do an int conv for a small speedup.